# How to layout text to flow around an image in xcode in ios (iphone)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Can you please tell me if there is a way to layout text around an image? Like this:

```
------  lbl lbl lbl
|img |  lbl lbl lbl
------  lbl lbl lbl
lbl lbl lbl lbl lbl
lbl lbl lbl lbl lbl
```

Please help me.

Comment: In what context? What have you already tried? There are a few solutions here, UIWebView, Text Kit, Core Text (if you dare).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily with Text Kit thanks to `NSTextContainer's` [`exclusionPaths`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSTextContainer_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTextContainer/exclusionPaths) property. [This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial) explains how to do that.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I have tried using NSTextContainer's exclusionPaths property but its not working for UILabel.